# select in insert trigger oracle after insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three table `CUSTOMER`, `PARAM_MASTER` and `CUSTOMER_PARAM`.  I wrote a trigger when inserting  table `CUSTOMER` to get data from table `PARAMS_MASTER` and get new `CUSTOMER_ID` which I want to insert into table `CUSTOMER_PARAM`.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "CUSTOMER_PARAM_INS_TRIG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMER 
for each row
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_PARAMS (PARAM_ID,PARAM_VALUE_EN,PARAM_VALUE_VI,CUSTOMER_ID)
  SELECT PARAM_ID,DEFAULT_VALUE_EN,DEFAULT_VALUE_VI,NEW:CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM PARAMS_MASTER,CUSTOMER 
  WHERE PARAM_GROUP='CUS';       
END;
```

Comment: What is the question?...

Comment: I am assuming you are getting a mutating exception?  if so you probably need to implement a 3 trigger approach or use a compound trigger.  However  could customer_params just be a view instead of an actual table?  then you wouldn't need to worry about a trigger just call the view whenever you need to access that data.

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger looks like it will throw a mutating table error.  This is because your trigger code includes a select on CUSTOMER, the table you're inserting into.

As it happens this select is unnecessary, because you only need the new  CUSTOMER_id.  So this should work:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "CUSTOMER_PARAM_INS_TRIG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMER 
for each row
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_PARAMS 
       (PARAM_ID,PARAM_VALUE_EN,PARAM_VALUE_VI,CUSTOMER_ID)
  SELECT PARAM_ID,DEFAULT_VALUE_EN,DEFAULT_VALUE_VI, :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID 
  FROM PARAMS_MASTER 
  WHERE PARAM_GROUP='CUS';       
END;
```